# How to remove timestamp in Month View of Matt Lewis Boostrap Calendar?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

MattLewis is a great calendar plugin but recently I got a problem in monthview. The month view shows Timestamp and it actually need to omit in my project.

Anyone who has a solution to my problem?

```
  Draggable event (00:00)
```

Thats the event look like but i want to remove `(00:00)`.

In previous version I already removed it but in the updated one i cant really find where they put the timestamp.

To remove in the older version here is what I did.

In calendarSlideBox.html in template

```
<a
      href="javascript:;"
      class="event-item"
      ng-click="vm.onEventClick({calendarEvent: event})">
      <span ng-bind-html="vm.$sce.trustAsHtml(event.title)"></span>
     <!-- (<span ng-bind="event.startsAt | calendarDate:(isMonthView ? 'time' : 'datetime'):true"></span><span ng-if="vm.calendarConfig.displayEventEndTimes && event.endsAt"> - <span ng-bind="event.endsAt | calendarDate:(isMonthView ? 'time' : 'datetime'):true"></span></span>)-->
    </a>
```

you will just comment out this part

```
<!-- (<span ng-bind="event.startsAt | calendarDate:(isMonthView ? 'time' : 'datetime'):true"></span><span ng-if="vm.calendarConfig.displayEventEndTimes && event.endsAt"> - <span ng-bind="event.endsAt | calendarDate:(isMonthView ? 'time' : 'datetime'):true"></span></span>)-->
```

but unfortunately I didn't find it in the new version.

Here is the calendarSlideBox.html in new version.

```
<a
          href="javascript:;"
          class="event-item"
          ng-click="vm.onEventClick({calendarEvent: event})">
          <span ng-bind-html="isMonthView ? vm.calendarEventTitle.monthView(event) : vm.calendarEventTitle.yearView(event) | calendarTrustAsHtml"></span>
        </a>
```

Anyone have an idea?